# Display query (select count group by) in a dataTable

Tags: java, jsf, datatable, richfaces

This query works fine at the console, But now I want to display it in the `xhtml` page in a `dataTable`, I have tried this `attemp` but it did not work

```
List<Object[]> results; 
public List<Object[]> getResults() {
results = entityManager.createQuery("select d.lib_naturepanne,count(r) as nbrr"+" from NaturePanne d JOIN d.listReparation r  GROUP BY d.lib_naturepanne").getResultList();

for (Object[] result : results) {
String name = (String) result[0];
int count = ((Number) result[1]).intValue();
System.out.println("name "+name+ " count "+count);

    }
return results;
```

file.xhtml

```
<rich:dataTable id="tablereparation"  value="#{stat.results}" var="rep">
<h:column headerClass="headerleftfacet">
<f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{rep.results.name}" /></h:column>

 <h:column headerClass="headermiddlefacet">
 <f:facet name="header">Count</f:facet>
  <h:outputText value="#{rep.results.count}" /></h:column>
 </rich:dataTable>
```

Comment: whats the error you get?

Comment: also add your managedbean impl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#{rep.results.name}` is wrong. You have a `List<Object[]>` so you either get the results like this: `#{rep[0]}`  or you map your Object[] to some kind of POJO.

```
public class NameCount {
    String name;
    int count;
    public NameCount(Object[] o) {
        name = (String) o[0];
        count = (Integer) o[1];
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
}

 public List<NameCount> getResults() {
    List<Object[]> results = entityManager.createQuery(...);

    List<NameCount> rowset = new ArrayList<NameCount>();
    for (Object[] o : results) {
        rowset.add(new NameCount(o));
    }
    return rowset;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks,I just want to test without POJO